# File glob to match both "version" and "version.h"

Tags: find, regular-expression, wildcards

I am trying to use `find` to identify all files in my repository named either "version" or "version.h", however I cannot come up with a valid glob to match to.

With regex I believe this would work: `.*/version\.*h*`

But I cannot come up with an equivalent in glob syntax.

Comment: Do you object to using “`-name version -o -name version.h`”?

Comment: That works :) I had not thought of that before

Answer (score 5):

> But I cannot come up with an equivalent in glob syntax.

I don't think you can, since regular globs don't have alternation or grouping. The closest you could get, would be `version*`, but of course that matches others too.

Though with a ksh-style extended glob or with zsh, you can do it:

(Bash)

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo **/version?(.h)
```

(ksh)

```
$ set -o globstar
$ echo **/version?(.h)
```

(zsh)

```
% echo **/version(|.h)
```

Many versions of `find` can use regexes too, but the available regex variants differ. BSD `find` defaults to basic regexes (BRE), but supports extended regexes with the `-E` flag:

```
$ find -E . -regex ".*/version(\.h)?"
```

In GNU `find` the [default is different](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions)<sup>(*)</sup>, but :

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/version(\.h)?"
```

Or you could use the simple solution, which Jeff suggested:

```
$ find . -name version -o -name version.h
```

Beware though that if adding an explicit *action* (instead of the default printing), you need parenthesis as in:

```
$ find . \( -name version -o -name version.h \) -a -exec ls -ld {} +
```

as `-a` (implied when omitted) has precedence over `-o`.

<sub>(* actually, the reference manual for GNU find doesn't seem to be able to decide what the default regex format is, compare the [last two entries here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#Full-Name-Patterns).)</sub>

Comment: `find -E` in BSD `find` for ERE (like in `sed` or `grep`)

Comment: @drewbenn, You sort of could. That's slightly different in that it creates two distinct globs. The result is different if `failglob` is set or `nullglob` unset, and one of the patterns doesn't match anything. (i.e. the command fails, or you get the nonmatching pattern as a literal)